# Control an Element in invisible Internet Explorer vba

Tags: java, vba, internet-explorer, automation, invisible

is there a way that i can control an invisible IE with this Element.
When IE is visible i can use focus and Sendkey functions. But don't know how, when it is invisible

```
<tr bgcolor="#c8d8f8">
<td valign=top colspan=2>
<b>Link_Nr / Link_St</b>
<br>
<input type="text" name="LINK" id="link" size="70" value="" 
onKeyUp="Auswahl_Link();">
</td>
</tr>
```

My way till now:

```
IEDocument.all.LINK.Value = linknummer
IEDocument.all.Item("Link").Focus ("Link")

If IEDocument.all.Item("Link").SetFocus Then
    Application.SendKeys "{UP}", True
End If
```

Comment: Please explain what 'an invisible IE' is; what does IE stand for?

Comment: Internet Explorer sorry

Comment: Is there an URL you could share? It may be possible to avoid Sendkeys. Also, are you tied to using Internet Explorer and are you allowed to install software on your machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using SendKeys to trigger the event when potentially you can trigger the event as shown below.

```
IEDocument.querySelector("#zeichn").fireEvent "onKeyUp"
```

or

```
IEDocument.getElementById("zeichn").fireEvent "onKeyUp"
```

I have never tried setting focus when IE.Visible = False but, if it is possible, then you may need to `.Focus`, on the element, before doing the above.

Comment: Thanks for helping, its work also when the IE is invisible